# How to remove gaps in x axis in matplotlib bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this simple example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.bar(x=[0,1,2], height=[10,8,6], width=0.5)
plt.show()
```

How can I remove the 0.5, 1.5 between the bars so that the x axis has integers of 0, 1, 2 only? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `plt.xticks(range(3))`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.bar(x=[0,1,2], height=[10,8,6], width=0.5)
plt.xticks(range(3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Edit

If you have gaps between your data, just use your x-values as input for `xticks`.

Code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x_data = [0, 1, 2, 5, 7]
y_data = [10, 8, 6, 3, 12]
plt.bar(x=x_data, height=y_data, width=0.5)
plt.xticks(x_data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: in my actual data, there may be gaps in between (for instance, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5), how can I achive this without explictly mentioning the range?

Comment: @crx91, see my edit